# Integration in the complex plane about the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to evaluate the integral $$ \oint_c\dfrac{dz}{\sin^2 z}$$ where $c$ is a circle $|z|=1/2$. The only pole within $c$ is $z=0$ and the residue at $z=0$ is found as $$\lim_{z\to 0}\dfrac{d}{dz}\left (\dfrac{z^2}{\sin^2 z}\right )=0$$ so that integral is zero. Where did I go wrong as it violates Cauchy Goursat theorem in complex integration.

Comment: how does it violate Cauchy's theorem?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing Cauchy's theorem with its converse. Your example shows that the converse of Cauchy's theorem is false, but that doesn't refute Cauchy's theorem itself.

Comment: I am under the impression that the converse is also true. is it Morera's theorem?

Comment: It's a quantifier issue. Morera's theorem says that a function is analytic if its integral is 0 around *every* closed curve. Nothing stops a non-analytic function from having an integral equal to zero around *some* closed curves.

Comment: Ok. That is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the residue at $z=0$ by directly evaluating the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in :-

$$\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(z)}=(z-\frac{z^{3}}{3!}+\frac{z^{5}}{5!}-...)^{-2}=z^{-2}(1-\frac{z^{2}}{3!}+\frac{z^{4}}{5!}-...)^{-2}$$.

Using Binomial theorem for negative index and $|z|<1$.

We get $$z^{-2}\left(1+2(\frac{z^{2}}{3!}-\frac{z^{4}}{5!})+( \text{powers of z greater than 1})\right)$$ .

So coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ is $0\,\,$ ( Which is exactly the definition of Residue at $0$ . It is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in Laurent Series expansion about $0$)

Hence By Cauchy Residue theorem . The integral is $0$.